Android Firebase a value is returning null from Realtime Database in RecyclerView
i try to set data from realtime database to recyclerview but it's returning null at Textview and ImageView, my data have text and url from storage, there my code:

Adapter:
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlantsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    PlantCategory plantCategory = plantCategoryList.get(position);
    if(plantCategory == null){
        return;
    }else {
        Glide.with(context)
                        .load(plantCategory.getCategoryImageURL())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.img_hard_level1)  // Hình ảnh placeholder tùy chọn
                .error(R.drawable.img_error_icon)
                                .into(holder.imgPlantCategory);
        holder.tvCategoryName.setText(""+plantCategory.getCategoryName());
    }
}
 public class PlantsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private ImageView imgPlantCategory;
    private TextView tvCategoryName;
    public PlantsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imgPlantCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_category);
        tvCategoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_plant_category);
        
    }
}

my fragment:
 `private List<PlantCategory> plantCategoryList;
        private void setPlantCategoryAdapter(){
        recyclerView = mView.findViewById(R.id.rcv_cate);
        plantCategoryAdapter = new PlantCategoryAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.item_category_search, this, R.id.rcv_cate);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        plantCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        plantCategoryAdapter.setData(plantCategoryList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(plantCategoryAdapter);
        getListCateGory();
    }
        private void getListCateGory(){
            DatabaseReference categoriesRef =            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category");
            categoriesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for( DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        PlantCategory category = snapshot.getValue(PlantCategory.class);
                            plantCategoryList.add(category);
                    }
                    plantCategoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "hhh" + error.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }`

example for my json structure:
"Category": {
        "1": {
            "CategoryID": 1,
            "CategoryName": "Dây leo",
            "CategoryImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/plant-box-b4958.appspot.com/o/Category%20Image%2FClimber.jpg?alt=media&token=e9b203e9-7bdf-478d-8575-9b2534ed7067"
        },
        "2": {
            "CategoryID": 2,
            "CategoryName": "Cây lá kim",
            "CategoryImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/plant-box-b4958.appspot.com/o/Category%20Image%2FConifers.jpg?alt=media&token=4ccd001b-dcb7-47d2-8b4c-f49406e528d1"
        }

My Realtime Database rules are set to true to both read and write. I've tried everything that I can from the internet but nothing seem to have an effect. How I can resolve this problem. Any help I can get I appreciate it really much.

help me guys please

Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your Firebase Console.
